# Best practice - for docu-Sign integration

Tags: integration, docusign

Can some provide best practice on docu-sign integration. like (when to choose docu-sign API & when to use apex code)
And lesson learned scenarios.

Comment: what is your use case for Docusign? How do you want to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to ask this is the Salesforce Success community, potentially the Process/Strategy group. Stackexchange is more question/answer style to solve a specific problem, rather than a general best practices discussion.

https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001oX2CAI